# Format and coordinate flip of the Projected Hartebeeshoek Coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, south-africa

Could someone please explain (or point me to a place that explains) what the coordinate system for Wg23 (Hartebeeshoek Lo23) should look like on a map? There is a coordinate flip that constantly comes into play, when I work with WG23 data, which I don not understand. This gets even messier when working with a modified grid (e.g. a mine grid).

My first coordinate (Easting I assume?) is usually negative, resulting in map displays that are North down. Occasionally I would receive similar data sets with the North up. I'm not sure when and how this flip is applied and how I should correct for it.

I work in QGIS and ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

North-down Wg23: Hartebeeshoek Lo23 (EPSG 2050) commonly come from land surveyor. It is official North-down CRS.

In QGIS:

- If you prefer North-up, **ZANGI:HBK_No_23**
- If you prefer North-down, then **EPSG 2050** (Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo23)

In ArcGIS:

- Only North-up is provided, **GCS_Hartebeesthoek_1994 / Lo23**